# Creating menuitems in xamarin.ios on a tabbed page using MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, toolbar, tabbedpage

I am creating a mobile app for android and ios using xamarin and MVVMCross.

In android I have created a tabbed page with 3 tabs using viewpager and toolbar.I have menuitems in the toolbar like Save,Sync etc. on click of which will save the content in each of the 3 tabs back into the database.

I want to implement the same in xamarin.ios but I see one problem here because if I create a tabbed page in ios using MvxTabBarController I am not sure if I can implement a similar concept of toolbar with menuitems where the menuitems will remain common across three tabs.
I am using MvvmCross so I have a MainViewmodel binding to MainViewController which will create 3 tabs for three child Viewmodels further having their respective Viewcontrollers attached.

In short my goal is to achieve the same I did for android application having common menuitems across 3 tabs.

Can anyone please help .....This is my first ios application !!

Thanks,
Santosh

Comment: If you want to show a toolBar on each child tab viewControllers. There're some differences between iOS and Android. You should create three toolBars for each child view to show it up.

Comment: Thanks if that's the case then I think it might be worth changing the layout in the android......may be a drawer layout having menuitems as I guess similar thing can be achieved in ios then.